# How to create array custom type in Commerce Tools

Tags: commercetools

I tried creating custom type in Commerce Tools to save multiple payment types in Profile.
I want to create custom type as array for cards to save in Commerce Tools how to do that?

"fields":[{
"bankName":"bankName",
"accountHolderName":"Name",
"encryptedCardNumber":"xxxxx1234",
"encryptedExpiryMonth":"12/10",
"encryptedSecurityCode":879,
"encryptedExpiryYear":"2030"
},
{
"bankName":"bankName2",
"accountHolderName":"Name",
"encryptedCardNumber":"xxxxx1234222",
"encryptedExpiryMonth":"12/10",
"encryptedSecurityCode":879,
"encryptedExpiryYear":"2030"
}

```
  ]
```